# mysql stored procedure to delete and perform insert

Tags: mysql

I have a use case where I need to delete data and do an insert with recent updates

1. Is there way I can do bulk delete and do an insert.
2. Table_A, has multiple subscription entries.
3. Table B has unique subscription
4. Table C is like a staging table  has multiple subscription, with a recent updates.

Once I delete the old entries, I can just do an insert.

Since table C does not have a key column, I can not perform  upsert

I an using

```
DELETE FROM table_A 
WHERE  subscription IN(SELECT subscription
                           FROM   table_b);
```

and then

```
Insert into table_A
SELECT subscription,
       <<other columns>>
from  table_C
```

Comment: What's your question? What you've written looks like it should work.

Comment: if you are updating table A, it shouldn't matter if table C has a key column. It's table A that may need a unique index

Comment: @Barner,@Garr Godferey,

My query works. I have these issues.

Comment: @Barner,@Garr Godferey,

My query works. I have these issues.

1)As it delete one subscription at time, these are not available to query till insert completes.
2) Performance issue - deleting one subscription at a time with in clause seems to be an issue. Is there way to do the bulk delete meaning, like stored procedure where I pass ex: 1000 subscription, delete those and insert. rather perform delete and insert. Hope I explained my problem,